# Batch command to delete files from file list

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

This code works fine. it deletes files from a file list:

```
For /f %%a in (file.lst) do del %%a
```

But why is the below one not working? It deletes the `.lst` file itself:

```
if exist file.lst (   
  set filelist="file.lst"    
) else (    
  set filelist="default.lst"    
)    
for /f %%b in (%filelist%) do del %%b
```

Also this is not working too:

```
for /f %%b in ("%filelist%") do del %%b
```

file.lst and default.lst contain something like this:

```
d:\1.txt    
d:\2.txt    
d:\abcd.bmp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for /f` interprets content of brackets like this:

- `file` - the file is processed line by line.
- `"text"` - only the text is processed.
- `'command'` - output of the command is processed line by line.

This is how you should edit your batch:

```
if exist file.lst (
    set "filelist=file.lst"
) else (
    set "filelist=default.lst"
)
for /f %%b in (%filelist%) do del "%%b"
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the need for `for` while deleting the list file? Just use something like:

```
if exist filename del filename
```

Comment: BTW, your first if-else code block works fine. The second for loop will also work, although if you have `set filelist="file.lst"` then `"%filelist%"` will cause the quotes to be doubled.

Comment: It doesnt delete list file when i mention the list file name. but it deletes the list file when i put the list file name in a variable.

Comment: Thanks Karan, i removed the quotes and it works:
set filelist=file.lst